# Accessing Ubuntu dekstop with SSH

Tags: ssh

I am trying to access my Ubuntu 16.04 desktop over SSH, but I keep getting the error 'Connection refused'. What I've done is the following:

- I first followed this http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/04/enable-ssh-ubuntu-16-04-lts/.
- Then I confirmed the correct port was mentioned sshd_config file.
- And I changed PermitRootLogin to yes.

But still I get connection refused when I enter ssh myubuntuusername@public-ip.

Does anyone have an idea what I can do? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is your system actually accessible at "public-ip"?

Comment: How do I check this? I've also tried the local IP, since I am often on the same WiFi network but also this returned 'connection refused'.

Comment: If you have some other service running on your system, try accessing that. But you would likely already know if your network was a configured for this desktop to publicly accessible at that IP. How did you set that up?

Comment: Try `ssh localhost` or `ssh 127.0.0.1` on the desktop itself. If that works, SSH is working and the rest is a network configuration issue.

Comment: I wonder if you might only have key/certificate authentication enabled, but aren't using a key to log in, so it's kicking you off immediately... or would that give a different error

Comment: ssh localhost works fine. I first had to accept that the authenticity of localhost could not be established, but after entering 'yes' and my password the connection is made.

Comment: I now get the following message when I try to connect from my laptop: ssh: connect to host xxx.xxx.xxx.xx port 22: Operation timed out

Comment: When I run netstat -lp I also do not see something listening specifically on port 22. Is that correct?

Comment: Also, when using the local ip I get Operation timed out, while when I use the global ip I get connection refused.